# How to prevent redirect to top when clicking on any link in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am going with a wired situation like the `preventDefault` function was working on my previous projects when I used it but in the current project, it's not working.

Always use this function for preventing any `URL` or `hash` or redirect after form submission, but in the current, it's only preventing the generating `hash` into the URL but it's scroll to top. Like in below code of `jsx` `next.js`

```
<Link href="#">
    <a
        onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); handleAddToCart()
        }}
    >
        <span>Add to Cart</span>
    </a>
</Link>
```

it's not generating the `hash` into the URL but it's scroll to top when clicking the `add to cart`.

I am not understanding what happening but how to overcome that situation?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a try with <Link href="">

Comment: remove the "a" node, if it's from MUI, then put the onClick on the Link, if it's from React Router, then don't use react router for the Link.

Answer (score 0):

For this case I wouldn't go with Link, anchor, can't you just use the `<button>`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this, because Link is using only for routing, not for onClick handler

```
<button onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); handleAddToCart()}}>
     Add to Cart
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using anchor tag inside the `Link`,

> Behind the scenes a `<Link>` renders an `<a>` with a real href, so people using the keyboard for navigation or screen readers will still be able to use this app. -[Source](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

But, `Link` provides more to do with it than `<a>`. When, you use `Link` it won't do a full page refresh to go the path because it's absolute, on the other hand, `<a>` will refresh the page to got the path as it's relative. More on that, that is why if you need to refresh a page in `react-router Link`, it provides the `refresh` method, see [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982).